# Google portable contacts api sort order not working

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, opensocial, google-contacts-api, portable-contacts

I am using this path to grab contacts from google after user is oauth2 authenticated.

> path =
>   "http://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/@me/@all/?count=500&fields=name,displayName,emails&sortBy=name"

Strangely the sortBy name is not working.

It gives:

1. First a list of unordered contacts with no order.
2. Then it gives contacts with name in alphabetical order.

I want all contact names sorted by alphabetical order.

What is the work around for this problem ?

A quick reply will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a google bug.

Check my discussion with Jospeh Smarr google opensocial apis lead.

http://groups.google.com/group/portablecontacts/browse_thread/thread/1a3e2d8f5b437e7c?pli=1